# Accessing Nokia N900 ssh via USB

Tags: usb, ssh

My MacBook Pro runs El Capitan. I have a Nokia N900 connected via USB. I am trying to access remotely its shell by the ssh protocol. How may I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I have been able to solve my issue.

1. Installed OpenSSH (server) from Application Manager
2. Connected the N900 to the Mac via USB and selected PC-Suite Mode
3. On the N900, as root, issued `ifup usb0` (activates USB)
4. On the N900, as root, issued `/etc/init.d/ssh start` (starts OpenSSH)
5. On the Mac, in Network Preferences (under System Preferences), selected the N900 and configured it manually to have the IP Address 192.168.2.14 and the Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 (at this point the N900 appears as correctly connected)
6. On the Mac, in Terminal, issued `ssh root@192.168.2.15`

At this point a confirmation is requested and I am prompted for the root password. Connection is then established.

I post all this in the hope of being useful to somebody, maybe with a different device. To be honest I do not understand fully all the passages, especially where I set the IP Address for the N900 as ...14 on the Mac, while by issuing `ifconfig` on the N900 the reported Address is ...15, and *this* has to be used in the final `ssh` command.

If anybody has comments which may me help to understand better what I have been doing, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! You could have asked your question on Unix StackExchange since it helped me on my Linux desktop. Starting SSH server manually should not be needed since it should automatically startup after boot. If you were confused about the IP addresses, the one you configured on your computer is the one that will be used to identify your computer and `192.168.2.15` is default IP address of N900.
By the way, it is not recommend to SSH as root, you can log in with `ssh user@192.168.2.15` after having set up a password with `passwd user` (root SSH can be disabled for better security).